# node.js "npm info it worked if it ends with ok"

Tags: node.js, dockerfile

I have the following errors running `npm install`:

```
npm info it worked if it ends with ok
npm info using npm@2.15.8
npm info using node@v4.4.7
npm ERR! install Couldn't read dependencies
npm ERR! Linux 4.4.15-moby
npm ERR! argv "/usr/local/bin/node" "/usr/local/bin/npm" "install"
npm ERR! node v4.4.7
npm ERR! npm  v2.15.8
npm ERR! path /app/package.json
npm ERR! code ENOPACKAGEJSON
npm ERR! errno -2
npm ERR! syscall open

npm ERR! package.json ENOENT: no such file or directory, open '/app/package.json'
npm ERR! package.json This is most likely not a problem with npm itself.
npm ERR! package.json npm can't find a package.json file in your current directory.

npm ERR! Please include the following file with any support request:
npm ERR!     /app/npm-debug.log
```

And this package.json:

```
{
  "name": "docker_web_app",
  "version": "1.0.0",
  "description": "Node.js on Docker",
  "author": "First Last <first.last@example.com>",
  "main": "server.js",
  "scripts": {
    "start": "node server.js"
  },
  "dependencies": {
    "express": "^4.13.3",
    "cassandra-driver": "*"
  }
}
```

I have followed this tutorial/description: https://alexanderzeitler.com/articles/debugging-a-nodejs-es6-application-in-a-docker-container-using-visual-studio-code/

Update: The official docker_hub Node.js is a MobyLinux and the terminal is really bad.

So basically `docker run -d -p 3000:3000 -p 5858:5858 hellovscode` it is the same as calling `npm install`

For the reference, the Dockerfile:

```
FROM node:4-onbuild

EXPOSE 3000
EXPOSE 5858
VOLUME /app
WORKDIR /app

RUN cd /app; npm install
CMD ["node", "--debug=5858","index.js"]
```

Comment: "If it worked it ends with ok" - since none of the lines end with ok, I guess none of them worked?